# Resizing a programatically loaded rectangle with DrawingManager

Tags: javascript, vue.js, azure-maps

I'm implementing a web app using Azure Maps with the DrawingManager library. I want to give my end users option to save a drawn rectangle and possibly edit it by resizing later. This should be possible given that resizing rectangles work perfectly fine straight after you add them.

There seems to be some issue around this when you add the shape programatically and the rectangle becomes.. a weird shape. You can reproduce this issue even with the online published example: https://samples.azuremaps.com/drawing-tools-module/load-data-into-drawing-manager when you try to resize a rectangle.

[image: example of the weirdly resized rectangle]

Maybe someone also came across this issue and found a solution or a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found what the problem was myself. It's not a bug in the library, just a bug in the example data.

The loaded figure should have the coordinates listed in reverse order. This works just fine with the library.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GeoJSON doesn't have a native rectangle object. If you are passing in a polygon that is a rectangle in shape, it will be treated as a polygon (what appears to be happening here).

If you know the polygon is a rectangle shape, you make use of the [extended GeoJSON specification in Azure Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/extend-geojson#rectangle) and add the `subType` property to your polygon to let the drawing manager know it is a rectangle.

For example:

```js
{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "subType": "Rectangle"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [[-122.35568,47.612875],[-122.28444,47.612875],[-122.28444,47.58046],[-122.35568,47.58046],[-122.35568,47.6128758]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, altough it doesn't address the problem here. 

When you add the polygon/rectangle using the draw manager, you can resize it just fine. However, when you add same object through code, you can't - and this is what's also happening in the link I put in my original post. 

The json objects of both shapes are identical, yet, in one case when you resize it, the coordinates are properly updated and in the other one - they become invalid.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, you can see the figure loaded in the example indeed has the subType: 'Rectangle' you mentioned, as from looking at the javascript you can see this figure is second on the list of features in this file: 
https://samples.azuremaps.com/data/geojson/randomFeatures.json